# NSObject does not seem to initialise before loading viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, nsobject

Apologies for the newbie question, but I am really struggling... I am having an issue trying to create a tableView datasource using a custom class of NSObject. I have managed to achieve this in a previous view controller, but when I try to replicate this it doesn't seem to work. It would appear that the init() function does not complete before the viewDidLoad() on the tableview and therefore data is only added to the source after the table is displayed.

The only difference I can see is that the viewController in which the tableView sits is part of a UITabBarController...

Here is the current code...

EventTableViewController.swift

```swift
import UIKit
import Foundation

class EventTableViewController: UIViewController  {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var eventModel = EventModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.dataSource = eventModel
        tableView.delegate = eventModel

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print("Table already loaded")

    }
}
```

EventModel.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Event {

    let eventName: String
    let eventType: String

    let eventStartDate: Date
    let eventEndDate: Date

    let participants: [String]

    init(item: PFObject) {
        self.eventName = (item["eventName"] as? String)!
        self.eventType = (item["eventType"] as? String)!
        self.eventStartDate = (item["startDate"] as? Date)!
        self.eventEndDate = (item["endDate"] as? Date)!
        self.participants = (item["eventParticipants"] as? [String])!
    }    
}

class EventModel: NSObject {

    var items = [Event]()

    override init() {
        // Setup the Events
        super.init()
        items = getAndConvertEvents()
    }


    func getAndConvertEvents() -> [Event] {

        var events = [Event]()
        let currentUser = PFUser.current()

        // Use this to get the events...!
        let query = PFQuery(className:"Events")
        query.whereKey("eventParticipants", contains: currentUser?.username)
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
            if let error = error {
                // Log details of the failure
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else if let objects = objects {
                // The find succeeded.
                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) events for user.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                for object in objects {
                    print(object.objectId as Any)
                }
                events = objects.map { Event.init(item: $0) }
            }
        }
        return events        
    }
}

extension EventModel: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? EventTableViewCell {

            // Set the table parameters
            cell.nameLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].eventName

        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

extension EventModel: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {

        return indexPath
    }
}
```

Is there anything that can be done to stop viewDidLoad() from finishing before the EventModel has finished loading?

**UPDATE**

I have included my appdelegate call to initialise the UITabBarController

AppDelegate.swift

```swift
import UIKit
import Parse
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
            $0.applicationId = ""
            $0.clientKey = ""
            $0.server = ""
            $0.isLocalDatastoreEnabled = true
        }
        Parse.initialize(with: configuration)

        let currentUser = PFUser.current()
        if currentUser != nil {
            // Do stuff with the user
            // Load the Event View as user is logged in
            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventTabController") as! UITabBarController
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        } else {
            // Show the signup or login screen
            let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let homePage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginView") as! StartVerificationViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = homePage
        }


        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `// Get the events from the datasource` happening? Is that some sort of asynchronous process?

Comment: It is a parse server request - sorry I didn't think it was massively relevant as again it is very similar to the other code I was using - have updated the original

Answer (score 0):

@maddy you were right...! I was calling an asynchronous process in the parse server call...! As always I should have posted the entire code - apologies I didn't even think that would be the issue!

I have now updated to do a synchronous call

```swift
    func getAndConvertEvents() -> [Event] {

            var events = [Event]()

            let currentUser = PFUser.current()

            // Use this to get the events...!
            let query = PFQuery(className:"Events")
            query.whereKey("eventParticipants", contains: currentUser?.username)
            do {
                let objects = try query.findObjects()
                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) events for user.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                for object in objects {
                    print(object.objectId as Any)
                }
                events = objects.map { Event.init(item: $0) }
            } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            return events
        }
```